# Get text from link - selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get "Home" text from

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

I tried

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name('active')
print element.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
```

but it returns empty string. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do it using CSS - `.find_element_by_css_selector("li.active a")`, or using xpath  `.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='active']/a")`

So this is how it would like finally

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.active a")
print element.text
```

Comment: Ok I finally found the real reason of my problem. I'm using http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ framework and when browser window is small it hides menu, and that's why I got blank text. Adding maximize_window() solved my problem. @amey thanks for your answer still very helpful as I'm a selenium beginner.

Comment: I had a similar problem to OP, I was trying to reference links that were part of like a sub-menu, and were therefore not visible on the screen. When I preformed the necessary actions to make them visible, I was able to read the text.