# Python Selenium Web-Driver not finding text element

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to get the product's seller yet it will not get the text. I assume this is some weird thing since the text is also a link. Any help?

Python Code:

```
self.sold_by = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sellerProfileTriggerId').text
```

HTML Element:

```
<a href="/gp/help/seller/at-a-glance.html/ref=dp_merchant_link?ie=UTF8&amp;seller=A2IEDZAWBB03ZE&amp;isAmazonFulfilled=1" id="sellerProfileTriggerId">SKUniverse</a>
```

Comment: think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251658/get-text-from-link-selenium-python/17254160

Comment: The mentioned element is with Id, I would suggest to use `self.sold_by = driver.find_element_by_id('sellerProfileTriggerId')`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
self.sold_by = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#sellerProfileTriggerId')
text_element=self.sold_by.text
print(text_element)
```

Also, why aren't you using `xpath` or `id` selectors! Just asking :)